# Why is $(AX)\cdot Y=X\cdot (A^{T}Y)$?

Tags: matrices

Can this equation $(AX)\cdot Y=Y\cdot (A^{T}X)$ be proved? where $A$ is a symmetric matrix, and $X$, $Y$ are the eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: The dot product is defined as $X\cdot Y=X^TY$. So $(AX)\cdot Y=(AX)^TY=X^TA^TY=X^T(A^TY)=X\cdot(A^TY)$. It has nothing to do with $X$ and $Y$ being eigenvectors.

Answer (score 2):

$$(AX)\cdot Y = \lambda X\cdot Y$$
$$Y\cdot (A^TX) = Y\cdot X \lambda = \lambda X\cdot Y$$
$$\Rightarrow (AX)\cdot Y = X\cdot(A^T Y)$$

Remember that in a symmetric matrix, $A = A^T$, and that the dot product of vectors is commutative.

Comment: could this be proved without using eigenvalues

Comment: Yes, you could just flip $Y\cdot (A^TX)$ and use the equality $A=A^T$. I figured that since you gave $X$ and $Y$ as eigenvectors that it was a practice problem that was intended to illustrate their usefulness.